# Css resource not available in jsp

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp

Hi I'm using spring and I want to include a css file.

I've created a folder resources/mytheme/css/signing.css under webapp.

My dispatcher servlet looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />

</beans>
```

In my jsp file I reference to the css file like this:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/signing.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

When I surf to the page I always get a 404 and  The requested resource is not available.

Someone who can help me?

Comment: Could you include how are you referencing your css in your jsp?

Comment: Sorry It wasn't included as code so it didn't show up.

Comment: If you go to: http://yourhost:8080/context/resources/css/signing.css you can't see your file? The jsp is being generated fine but without the css?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Just a 404.

Comment: But can you access your jsp page?

Comment: No, I can't acces anything. When I remove the mvc:resources in my dispatcher then it displays my jsp but it doens't load the css.

Comment: Ok, could you include your web.xml? are you using annotations for your controller? are you following any tutorial?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: Ok, check that you have a missing line after mvc:resources -> <mvc:annotation-driven />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding this to my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This makes my resource folder available.